# add class current when slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to create simple accordion menu with simple code.

Here is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/)

```
$('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

my problem is how to add class `current` to parent li when slidedown, something like below:

```
<ul>
    <li class="current">
        level 2
```

and remove class `current` when slide is closed.

Comment: Have you considered jQuery UI's accordion widget? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @ryan thanks.. i know we can found alot in web.. but i tried to understand how it work with little snippet code .. hope you understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, this will do the trick.

```
$('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle('slow', function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
    });
    ev.stopPropagation();
});​
```

And [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcW84/) of that example with a colored background to visualize `.current`